# KAA ESP8266 Queries

Tags: esp8266, kaa

I compiled configuration demo for ESP8266 by using Xtensa-lx106 GNU

file demo_client

demo_client: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Tensilica Xtensa, version 1 (SYSV), corrupted program header size, not stripped

Could you please tell me, how can i flash this application to ESP8266 by using espytoo.py and how to test it.

I also not able to get GPIO ESP8266 controll application in my sandbox image. 
Could you please tell me how can i test gpio control application with nodemcu esp8266 and android app.

Thanks

Rurban

Comment: Can anyone have any suggestion for this queries?

Answer (score 0):

To create a binary from the ELF file:

```
esptool.py elf2image demo_client
```

After this, to flash the board with the application:

```
sudo esptool.py write_flash 0x00000 demo_client-0x00000.bin 0x40000 demo_client-0x40000.bin
```

If necessary, you can specify the serial port with *--port* argument.

Regarding GPIO demo for ESP8266, [here](https://github.com/vadimol/kaa_gpio_esp8266_example) is an example of GPIO slave application that works with Kaa 0.10.

Comment: Thank you for help but i am not able to find the GPIO slave application in above link. Could you please provide the proper link.

Comment: Fixed the link. Thanks.